# Django Authentication, should frontend connect to remote database using API or SSH key?

Tags: django, api, ssh, frontend, backend

I'm new to backend and now in my backend, I have a database and server connecting, I'm trying to build a login and registration function. And in my frontend, I'm not connecting to my database directly.

My question is, should I connect to my database using my ssh key so that I can register a user directly on my frontend? Or should I just post my username and password to the backend using my API? But for this approach, how to encode the password and save it to the user authentication table?

Or both of my ideas above are not appropriate? Normally, what would developers do to register and login a user when having a remote server and database?

Any idea would be appriciated. Thanks for your help!

Kind regards,

Xi

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why aren't you using the built-in authentication and best practices now that you are using Django?

Comment: Hi @Selcuk , thanks for you reply. Yes, I'm using Django, the bulit-in authentication will authenticate a new user by going through my local database, is that right? But I haven't connected my remote database to my frontend yet, should I do that?

Comment: You seem to have been confused with terminology. The frontend typically doesn't communicate with the database, the backend does. You should read a few tutorials on modern web application architecture first.